# Why is the background (bg) colour not changing and looking so weird in my python GUI using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, schedule

I have to do a school project and in the code I have a problem, my buttons look so weird white, where I can't read what I wrote and when I want to change the background colour nothing is working. Yes I could change the font colour (fg), but I would like to keep it as white and just change the background colour. You can see in the code I put below that at the end of it I changed the bg to different colours, but it doesn't show up and also tried using hex code. I would really appreciate help, thanks a lot! I also included a screenshot of the GUI so you can see how its looking. I am using Python 3 and tkinter. [image]

Here is some code out of my program:

```
    """Retrieving the Envents"""
def retrieveTab(self):
    root2=tkinter.ttk.LabelFrame(self.tab2, text="Retrieve")
    greetings=tkinter.ttk.Label(self.tab2,text="Hello there!Please click on the day you want to retrieve",font=self.customFont)
    greetings.grid(column=0,row=0,pady=5)
    
    def printAllEvent():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("text.txt",'a')
        if os.stat("text.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, No Event Found")
        else:
            with open ("text.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("text.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printMonday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("monday.txt","a")
        if os.stat("monday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Monday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("monday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("monday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printTuesday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("tuesday.txt","a")
        if os.stat("tuesday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Tuesday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("tuesday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("tuesday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printWednesday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("wednesday.txt",'a')
        if os.stat("wednesday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Wednesday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("wednesday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("wednesday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printThursday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("thursday.txt",'a')
        if os.stat("thursday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Thursday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("thursday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("thursday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printFriday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("friday.txt",'a')
        if os.stat("friday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Friday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("friday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("friday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printSaturday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("saturday.txt",'a')
        if os.stat("saturday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Saturday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("saturday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("saturday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
    def printSunday():
        showbiz.delete(1.0,END)
        file_new=open("sunday.txt",'a')
        if os.stat("sunday.txt").st_size == 0:
            showbiz.insert(INSERT,"Sorry, Sunday is Empty")
        else:
            with open ("sunday.txt","a")as file_new:
                file_new=open("sunday.txt")
                contents=file_new.read()
                showbiz.insert(INSERT,contents)
                showbiz.see(INSERT)
   
    monday=Button(self.tab2, text="Monday",bg="blue",fg="white",font=("Arial",14),command=printMonday).grid(column=0,row=2,ipadx=18,pady=5)
    tuesday=Button(self.tab2, text="Tuesday",bg="red",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printTuesday).grid(column=1,row=2,ipadx=11,pady=5)
    wednesday=Button(self.tab2, text="Wednesday",bg="green",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printWednesday).grid(column=0,row=3,pady=5)
    thursday=Button(self.tab2, text="Thursday",bg="#4d79ff",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printThursday).grid(column=1,row=3,ipadx=10,pady=5)
    friday=Button(self.tab2, text="Friday",bg="#009900",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printFriday).grid(column=0,row=4,pady=5,ipadx=24)
    saturday=Button(self.tab2, text="Saturday",bg="#ff5050",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printSaturday).grid(column=1,row=4,ipadx=15,pady=5)
    sunday=Button(self.tab2, text="Sunday",bg="#ffc34d",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printSunday).grid(column=0,row=5,pady=5,ipadx=20)
    showbiz=Text(self.tab2,width=97,height=22)
    showbiz.grid(columnspan=3)
    allEvent=Button(self.tab2, text="All Events",bg="orange",fg="white",font=("Helvetica",14),command=printAllEvent).grid(column=1,row=5,ipadx=8,pady=5)
```

Comment: Need to see your import statement for tkinter.  If ```root``` and ```greetings``` have ```tkinter.ttk.``` then the buttons might need this format too??

Comment: @InhirCode - I x2 your statement. I think adding the import in front will maybe solve this - tkinter.Button

Comment: yeah -hopefully. I do wonder if it is a good idea to mix the themes style ttk with straight tkinter widgets. Might work better to have one or the other.